# работа со списками в python

Tags: python

Обязательно ли инициализировать список `array` для того, чтобы заполнить его значениями в этом фрагменте? Если нельзя, то можно ли как-нибудь экономично заполнить этот список? Почему не получается добавить элементы в `array`?

```
array = []
N = 10
value = int(input())
max_value_1 = 1
max_value_2 = 1

while N>0:
    array[value%8] = value

    if value > max_value_1:
        max_value_1 = value
    elif value >max_value_2:
       max_value_2 = value
N -=1

print(max_value_1*max_value_2)
```

Comment: Ваш код  даже не проходит валидацию перед запуском. Отступы у `while` неверные; возможно, бесконечный цикл или же повтор одинаковых операций в цикле. Для начала исправьте, а потом уже будем разбираться, что не получается. Иначе вообще непонятно чем и как этот список нужно заполнять.

Comment: @kff хорошо, сейчас переделаю

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы не можете записывать элементы по индексу, если список не заполнен.
И либо вы инициализируете список начальными значениями:

```
array = [0 for _ in range(10)]
```

Либо добавляете по мере поступления:

```
array = []
array.append(10)
```

Comment: `array = [0] * 10` работает хорошо для неизменяемых объектов таких как целые числа в Питоне.